# Christoffel symbols of Poincaré metric using orthonormal tetrad formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I want to calculate the Christoffel symbols for the Poincaré metric using the orthonormal tetrad formalism.

$$ds^2 = y^{-2}dx^2 + y^{-2}dy^2.$$

I introduce a non coordinate orthonormal basis with one-forms

$$ds^2 = (\omega^{\hat{x}})^2 + (\omega^{\hat{y}})^2.$$

The new basis one forms can be identified as

$$\omega^{\hat{x}} = y^{-1}dx $$
$$\omega^{\hat{y}} = y^{-1}dy. $$

I calculate the exterior derivatives

$$d (\omega^{\hat{x}}) = d(y^{-1}dx) = - y^{-2} dy \wedge dx = -  \omega^{\hat{y}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{x}} = \omega^{\hat{x}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{y}}$$
$$d (\omega^{\hat{y}}) = d(y^{-1}dy) = 0$$
$$d (\omega^{\hat{x}}) = -\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{i}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{i}} = -\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{x}} - \Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{y}} $$

$$\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y} } = - \omega^{\hat{x}}, \,\,\,
\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x} } =  \omega^{\hat{y}}$$

$$\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y} \hat{x}} = -1, \,\,\, \Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x} \hat{y}} = 1$$

Transformation matrices are:
$$
\Lambda^{\hat{a}}_{\;b}  = \begin{bmatrix}
    y^{-1}       & 0   \\
    0       & y^{-1}   \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
(\Lambda^{-1}) ^{a}_{\;\hat{b}}  = \begin{bmatrix}
    y       & 0   \\
    0       & y   \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
hence
$$\Gamma^{x}_{\;yx} = (\Lambda^{-1}) ^{x}_{\;\hat{x}} \Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y} \hat{x}} 
(\Lambda) ^{y}_{\;\hat{y}} (\Lambda) ^{x}_{\;\hat{x}} = -y^{-1} $$

The solution is correct, but for all other Christoffel symbols I get $0$.

Correct solutions should be

$$\Gamma^{x}_{xx} = 0, \ \ \ \Gamma^{x}_{yx} = \frac{-1}{y}, \ \ \ \Gamma^{y}_{xx} = \frac{1}{y}, \ \ \  \Gamma^{y}_{yy} = \frac{-1}{y}$$

How can I get

$$\Gamma^{y}_{xx} = \frac{1}{y}, \ \ \  \Gamma^{y}_{yy} = \frac{-1}{y}~?$$

The procedure I follow is based on Relativity Demistified from David McMahon (Chapter 5)

Comment: How did you get zero for the others? Note that the one form $\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\hat{x}}$ doesn't have to be zero, it has to be a multiple of $\omega^{\hat{x}}$.

Comment: That is true. I updated the question, but how can I continue? I don't know a and b.

Comment: Actually by their antisymmetry, they are zero.

Comment: But b = 0 implies $\Gamma^{\hat{y}}_{\;\hat{y} } = 0$, which implies $\Gamma^{y}_{yy} = 0$, while  $\Gamma^{y}_{yy} = \frac{-1}{y}$ (checked via other way + EinsteinPy)

Comment: It doesn't imply $\Gamma^y_{yy}=0$. You have that $\Gamma^y_{yy}=(\Lambda^{-1})^y_{\hat{d}}\Gamma^{\hat{d}}_{\hat{e}\hat{f}}\Lambda^{\hat{e}}_{y}\Lambda^{\hat{f}}_{y}$, which is not going to be zero, one of the summands has $\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\hat{x}\hat{y}}=-1$ .

Comment: When upper index and lower index are different in my case the $\Lambda$ is zero. Only way to come to the correct solution is chosing $\Gamma^{\hat{y}}_{\;\hat{y} } = - \omega^{\hat{y}}$. That means choosing b equal to -1. I see that only postfactum, after I did the calculation of the Christoffel symbols in another way.

Comment: In the mean time I got the correct solution. Thanks for the help. But during the process I had to make some guesses. E.g. $\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x} } =  \omega^{\hat{y}}$ could also have been $\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x} } =  0$ I could not know that in advance.  I could only know that because I did the calculation in advance in another way. This procedure gives me only a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ds^2 = y^{-2}dx^2 + y^{-2}dy^2.$$

I introduce a non coordinate orthonormal basis with one-forms

$$ds^2 = (\omega^{\hat{x}})^2 + (\omega^{\hat{y}})^2.$$

The new basis one forms can be identified as

$$\omega^{\hat{x}} = y^{-1}dx $$
$$\omega^{\hat{y}} = y^{-1}dy. $$

I calculate the exterior derivatives

$$d (\omega^{\hat{x}}) = d(y^{-1}dx) = - y^{-2} dy \wedge dx = -  \omega^{\hat{y}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{x}} = \omega^{\hat{x}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{y}}$$
$$d (\omega^{\hat{y}}) = d(y^{-1}dy) = 0$$
$$d (\omega^{\hat{x}}) = -\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{i}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{i}} = -\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{x}} - \Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y}} \wedge \omega^{\hat{y}} $$

$$\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y} } = - \omega^{\hat{x}}, \,\,\,
\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x} } =  \omega^{\hat{y}}$$

$$\Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y} \hat{x}} = -1, \,\,\, \Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{x} \hat{y}} = -1$$

$$\Gamma^{\hat{y}}_{\;\hat{y} } = - \omega^{\hat{y}}, \,\,\,
\Gamma^{\hat{y}}_{\;\hat{x} } =  \omega^{\hat{x}}$$

$$\Gamma^{\hat{y}}_{\;\hat{y} \hat{y}} = -1, \,\,\, \Gamma^{\hat{y}}_{\;\hat{x} \hat{x}} = 1$$

Transformation matrices are:
$$
\Lambda^{\hat{a}}_{\;b}  = \begin{bmatrix}
 y^{-1}       & 0   \\
 0       & y^{-1}   \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
(\Lambda^{-1}) ^{a}_{\;\hat{b}}  = \begin{bmatrix}
 y       & 0   \\
 0       & y   \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
hence
$$\Gamma^{x}_{\;yx} = (\Lambda^{-1}) ^{x}_{\;\hat{x}} \Gamma^{\hat{x}}_{\;\hat{y} \hat{x}} 
(\Lambda) ^{y}_{\;\hat{y}} (\Lambda) ^{x}_{\;\hat{x}} = -y^{-1} $$

The other Christoffel symbols can be calculated in a similar way.

The solutions  are correct.

$$\Gamma^{x}_{xx} = 0, \ \ \ \Gamma^{x}_{yx} = \frac{-1}{y}, \ \ \ \Gamma^{y}_{xx} = \frac{1}{y}, \ \ \  \Gamma^{y}_{yy} = \frac{-1}{y}$$